# HTML5 inputs on the Android browser

Tags: android, html, input, types, numbers

iPhone's Mobile Safari seems to recognize most new HTML5 input types, in particular the ones detailed [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm), such that tapping in an input declared like so:

```
<input type="number" id="myInput" value=""/>
```

presents the iPhone's numeric keypad.

However, in the Android browser, the usual text keypad is shown when tapping the same input.

Is there a workaround for the Android browser or an alternative attribute that can be set or even a library I can include to have the android browser respect this setting?

Answer (score 1):

if you specify on the input element the type as "number" it will automatically open with the numeric keypad
example

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="amount_zip" value="loading.."></input>
```

the pattern attribute is for iPhone,

you can also get more info on inputs [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `<input type="number">` with a Xoom (Honecomb, I think) and it *does* cause the numeric keypad to open, which is great, but the field only appears to allow positive integers.  Hitting the '-' and '.' keys on the keypad have no effect.  Adding relevant min / max attributes or setting a proper pattern don't seem to have any effect.  In other words, if you want the keyboard to appear and your numeric field only needs to be zero or a positive integer, this will work.  Otherwise (floats, negative numbers), you'll have to use text.

(I realize I'm not answering the question here, I would like to have left this as a comment for the previous answer, but can't figure out how)